# How to efficiently search raw byte data for first instance of specific DWORD value in C#?

Tags: c#

In C/C++ you could do this `O(n)` with a pointer to a buffer and casting to 32bit datatype, but in C# given `byte[]` or `IEnumerable<byte>` and an `int32` how might you efficiently find the first position of the DWORD in the byte buffer, ideally using built-in library methods?

I don't want to venture into unsafe code so I can of course search for a 4-element byte sub-buffer. But is there a neater way to take advantage of my search value being 32bits long?

Trivial workup (pseudo-ish):

```
int Find(IEnumerable<byte> buf, int val)
{
 byte d = val & 0xff, c = (val >>8) & 0xff, b = (val >>16) & 0xff, a = (val>>24) & 0xff;
 for(int i=0;i<buf.Length - 3;++i)
 {
  if(buf[i] == d && buf[i+1] == c && buf[i+2] == b && buf[i+3] == a)
   return i
 }
 return -1;
}
```

Basically wondering if I can combine all 4 byte-wise checks with a single 32-bit check.

Comment: Could you please share some code samples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: why not using a for loop and break once 4 subsequent items are what you're looking for ?

Comment: Are you certain off the byte order?

Comment: @ChrisBD ah I meant to use system-default, did I get that wrong? I'm working on dual-endian code and am confused which is normal now :) You can edit or I will if needed

Answer (score 0):

> wondering if I can combine all 4 byte-wise checks with a single 32-bit check

Not without violating alignment.  Some options you do have are:

1. a masked 32-bit comparison against the first part of the value for each of the 4 possible alignments (this will be testing 32, 24, 16, or 8 bits).  After you get a success, you'll still have to test against the remaining bits
2. A SIMD comparison looking for the first byte (or most unique -- I certainly wouldn't want to search for `0x00` since there will be far more than 0.5% false positives) of the needle at 16 or so possible adjacent locations simultaneously.  Once you get a match you need to test the three following bytes also.

Comment: Ben I'd love, simply out of curiosity, to see an example of option 2. I've used SIMD low-level before but never seen it utilised in C#

Comment: @Mr.Boy: It seems like you'd use `System.Numerics.Vector<byte>` and call [`EqualsAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.equalsany?view=netcore-3.1).